# Symfony2: form entity group_by ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a formtype with this entry:

```
->add('work', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeAdminBundle:Work',
    'property' => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('work')
            ->orderBy('work.name', 'ASC');
    },
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'group_by' => 'artists'
))
```

I'm trying to group the works by their artists name. The problem is that the artists are a ManyToMany like this:

```
class Work
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="works")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="works_artists")
     */
    protected $artists;
```

I tried setting the group_by to "artists" and "artists.name" but neither work. I only get a PHP error.

Does anyone know how to do it or if it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `'group_by' => 'artists.name'` in query builder

```
->add('work', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeAdminBundle:Work',
    'property' => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('work')
        ->orderBy('work.name', 'ASC');
    },
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'group_by' => 'artists.name'

))
```

**Edit** try using `choices` option in the entity type field i have called another function which creates the choice list as group of arrays like group of  for each artist with their workers make sure you properly define the getters in the function i have used dummy like `getName()`

```
->add('work', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeAdminBundle:Work',
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'choices' => $this->getOptGropupForEntities()

))


public function getOptGropupForEntities(){
    $artists = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeAdminBundle:Artists')->findAll();
    $list = array();
    foreach($artists as $a){
        $name = $a->getName();
        if(count($a->getWorks())>0){
            foreach($a->getWorks() as $w){
                $list[$name][$w->getId()] = $w->getName();
            }
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 60 near 'artists ORDER': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.`

Comment: @DiegoCastro my bad i have not joined the artists entity,see my updated answer and make sure artists entity should have $id property

Comment: Well, that does not seem to solve my problem. On the select rendered by the formtype the works are not grouped by their artists name =/

Comment: What is the name of property in your artists entity change `->groupBy('a.propertyname')` according to the property

Comment: It is `->groupBy(a.name)` but it seems that I have to put something in the `group_by` option. The select is not rendering with the optgroup with the artists name

Comment: @DiegoCastro the last thing but not the least i can update is try with `'group_by' => 'artists.name'` following the [feature request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1735) let me know if it works

Comment: No luck my friend =/ I'm using symfony 2.4 and it seems to just ignore the `'group_by' => 'artists.name'

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but it gives me an error: `ContextErrorException: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php line 90`